# How to enter "<=" symbol inside HTML tags in Joplin note taking app?

Tags: html, ubuntu, html-table

I am using the app "joplin-desktop" in Ubuntu 20.04

I have constructed a HTML table and then I am writing `<td><=</td>`

But instead of getting a plain output of `<=` I am getting an output of `<=< td="" class="jop-noMdConv">`

So how can I get a plain output of `<=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&lt;` instead of `<`. `&lt;` is a HTML entity to represent the less than sign.